# Universal Windows Apps: programmatically change font sizes application wide

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

In a UWP app I'd like to implement the capability of allowing the user to increasing/decreasing various font sizes (titles, subtitles, normal text, etc.) and was looking for a smart way of achieving this.

Bindings in style setters don't work in UWP and if possibile I'd like to leverage themes for font resizing.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: The user can scale the fonts across the device without you doing it manually. Its probably best to let them change it using the built-in font scaling across all applications than making them do it in each individual application. Plus Microsoft might not like it.

Comment: Forcing to change font size device wide only because in my app default text size in not appropriate for a given user does not seem to me a great idea. I've seen store apps that typically provide 3 sets of font sizes to choose from. I was only wondering what could be the best technical approach to achieve this result. I was thinking about a style selector.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may make a Xaml with some style about the font and make user to select the style from xaml.In UWP change the style is easy.

And I think you may used the `StaticResource` ，try use the `DynamicResource` and when used increasing font you can change the resource.

Comment: DynamicResource is not available in UWP